# 504 Server Error with nested include()

Tags: php, linux, apache, include

I have a PHP application that has multiple "nested" include() functions. For some reason the applications stops after 60 seconds. I'm using set_time_limit(0), also I have tested this without the include function in the file and it runs forever. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Working:

```
set_time_limit(0);

while(1 < 2){
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Not Working:

```
//MASTER FILE
set_time_limit(0);

while(1 < 2){
    include('file.php');
}

//INCLUDED FILE 'file.php'
echo 'hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's bad practice to write infinite loops, especially in response to a web request.  In general you also want your web requests to respond as quickly as possible and have long-running processes run separately.

That said, assuming you're running PHP behind Apache, you'll want to adjust your [Apache `TimeOut` config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout).  It defaults to 60 seconds.

Comment: Firstly, I'm aware it is generally bad practice to write infinite loops. Although the loop only runs when a variable, as set in a mysql database is set to "1", and is definitely not used for requests. With that said, I'm aware of the TimeOut property. The issue only seems to occur when I have `include()` functions in my script. Thank you for your input!